# Regex "findall" + the next seven characters

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm having trouble finding a solution to the following:

I run `output = requests.get(url, headers=headers)` and then save the content to a file "output_file", so far so good.

I then read that file as utf-8 and perform the following:

```
url_end = '/video-'
links = re.findall(url_end, output_file)
```

As expected I'm presented with 30 or so matches to '/video' however, here's the question.

**How do I also return the next 7 random characters after the "-"?** They're like youtube video IDs, completely random and unique.

In fact, if anyone knows how to find just the random 7 characters that would work too, I can add the /video- prefix after.

Here is an example URL: `https://example.com/video-nsuef0f/`

Comment: what's wrong with `url_end = r'/video-.{7}'` ?

Comment: Well nothing... that's the answer I was looking for. I think the problem was between the chair and the keyboard. Thank you though, I was getting frustrated!

Comment: You should comprehensively read through the Python documentation for `re`